# In Google sheets, I am trying to display the top 3 values in a list in order on another page

Tags: google-sheets

So I have a list of names on the first column and next to them some numbers; i.e.

```
James | 1638

Mike  | 2988

Emily | 2212

Suzi  | 3300
```

In the above example, I would want to show that suzi has come first, Mike second and Emily third with the amounts, how can I do this?

Comment: Can you sort the rows based on the second column?

Answer (score 1):

If your first sheet has this in cells A1:B5

```
Name  | Number
James | 1638
Mike  | 2988
Emily | 2212
Suzi  | 3300
```

On the second sheet in (say) A2 enter

```
=sort(Sheet1!A2:B5,2,false)
```

If you want to show only the top 3, you can use

```
=query(sort(Sheet1!A2:B5,2,false),"select * limit 3")
```